# Facebook crossdomain.xml silverlight error

Tags: silverlight, facebook, cross-domain, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a problem with crossdomain.xml that is located on Facebook photo servers. The first problem arises when Silverlight asks for clientaccesspolicy.xml – Facebook servers return 403 – Access Denied which is fine, since they also have crossdomain.xml deployed on their servers. Silverlight then asks for that crossdomain.xml and the response it gets is exactly this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain- policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Then I played for a while with this, deployed that crossdomain.xml to my own servers and a got the same results – a security exception. Then I started moving things out and came to a conclusion that everything will work as desired if I only remove the **to-ports="*"** attribute? Does anyone has an idea how to overcome this, has anyone had the same problem before or is it something that I’m doing wrong?

Comment: I can access photos on facebook without issue, so more information is needed about what are you doing exactly.

Comment: I can also access photos on facebook, but just for viewing, but since silverlight doesn't allow bitmap editing on cross domain sources this is where the problem arises. Here is a piece of code that can be used to reproduce this problem:

`public void DownloadPhoto(string uri)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        }`

Comment: I just found some information that silverlight does not support _to-ports_ attribute in [this tread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/48275.aspx/1/10#138055)

Comment: hmm, looks like a new issue. My facebook app worked just a month ago then I converted to signed requests, but it appears to be broken now.

Comment: Exactly, It wasn't like this before. I created a new [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19406), although this is not exactly facebook bug.

Comment: I do wonder why did they add to-ports="*" to the crossdomain file. The only usable port on their photo servers is the default 443, so why bother to allow all other ports? I am starting to feel like Don Quixote trying to keep my silverlight application alive on the facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue while trying to programmatically retrieve images from Facebook. The strange part is that if you point a Silverlight image control to the Facebook image url, the image is retrieved and displayed without error. This got me thinking and I have come up with a viable workaround that seems to work consistently for my situation. I hope you find it useful too.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/mglace/picture/", UriKind.Absolute);
var bmp = new BitmapImage();

bmp.ImageOpened += (sender, e) => { /* Do something here with the sender (which is the BitmapImage) */ };
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bmp.UriSource = uri;
```

Create a `BitmapImage` object, set an event handler for the `ImageOpened` event and set the `CreateOptions` property to `BitmapCreateOptions.None`.  Finally, set the `UriSource` to the Facebook image you want to retrieve. The image is downloaded immediately because we set the `CreateOptions` to `None` (the default value is `DelayedCreation`).  You can then perform any actions you would like in the `ImageOpened` event handler.

I wanted to encapsulate this logic in my service layer and beef up the error handling and such so I wrapped it in a Reactive Extensions observable to make it easier to use.  Here is my final code snippet:

```
public IObservable<BitmapImage> GetProfilePhoto(string profileId)
{
    return Observable.Create<BitmapImage>(
        observer =>
            {
                // This handler handles a successful fetch
                EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> openedHandler =
                    (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                observer.OnNext(sender as BitmapImage);
                                observer.OnCompleted();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                observer.OnError(ex);
                            }
                        };

                // This handler handle a failure
                EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs> failedHandler =
                    (sender, args) => observer.OnError(args.ErrorException);

                var url = string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture/", profileId);
                var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

                BitmapImage bmp = null;

                try
                {

                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        () =>
                            {
                                bmp = new BitmapImage();

                                bmp.ImageOpened += openedHandler;
                                bmp.ImageFailed += failedHandler;

                                bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                                bmp.UriSource = uri;
                            });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                }

                return () =>
                            {
                                // Cleanup the event handlers
                                if (bmp != null)
                                {
                                    bmp.ImageOpened -= openedHandler;
                                    bmp.ImageFailed -= failedHandler;
                                }
                            };
            });
}
```

And usage:

```
GetProfilePhoto("mglace")
    .Subscribe(image => { /* Do something with the image in here*/  },
               error => { /* Handle any errors in here */ },
               () => { /* Finalization code goes here */ });
```

I hope someone out there finds this useful.

Comment: I used your code and it worked like a charm. I want to know if there is any possibility to get image's stream, so the image could be edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not resolved in Silverlight 5. Facebook doesn't seem concerned too.

Comment: Any idea why the user gets a 403 status response when trying to access the clientaccesspolicy.xml file?